# JsReport: Recipe: xlsx - Charts data not getting refreshed

Tags: handlebars.js, xlsx, jsreport

I'm using xlsx recipe with engine handlebars, after generating the report data is not reflecting on charts and excel prompting the below waring message

[image]

Here is the [playground link](https://playground.jsreport.net/w/anon/yg6CuNM1)

Code block:

```
{{xlsxRemove "xl/worksheets/sheet2.xml" "worksheet.sheetData[0].row" 1}}

{{#each scanData}}
{{#xlsxAdd "xl/worksheets/sheet2.xml" "worksheet.sheetData[0].row"}}
<row>
    <c t="inlineStr" s="{{@root.$removedItem.c.[0].$.s}}"><is><t>{{email}}</t></is></c>
    <c t="inlineStr" s="{{@root.$removedItem.c.[1].$.s}}"><is><t>{{firstName}}</t></is></c>
    <c t="inlineStr" s="{{@root.$removedItem.c.[2].$.s}}"><is><t>{{lastName}}</t></is></c>
    <c t="inlineStr" s="{{@root.$removedItem.c.[3].$.s}}"><is><t>{{organizationName}}</t></is></c>
    <c s="{{@root.$removedItem.c.[4].$.s}}"><v>{{scans}}</v></c>
</row>
{{/xlsxAdd}}
{{/each}}

{{{xlsxPrint}}}
```

Thanks in advance!

As per the documentation and samples provided by JsReport forum I tried multiple charts with valid data, always I'm facing an issue with the Data model is preventing Microsoft Excel from opening this workbook.

My expectation is based on the data the charts needs to be refreshed and updated.